# ListView different ImageViews in one row (each one clickable itself)

Tags: android, listview, row

I would like to make a ListView, all ImageViews should be in this order:

[Order of ImageViews](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/2563/52261868.jpg)

I would like to select ImageView1 then ImageView2, but at the moment I can only select row1 or row2.

```
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("Image1", R.drawable.IMG1);
    map.put("Image2", R.drawable.IMG2);
```

Hope you can help me...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using a Grid View:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html